# SSH connection timed out Win 7 Cygwin

Tags: windows-7, ssh, home-networking

Trying to establish ssh connection to my own computer.
Running cygwin on Windows 7. Have openssh installed using this guide: http://lifehacker.com/205090/geek-to-live--set-up-a-personal-home-ssh-server.

Using port 2000 because router doesn't allow port forward on 22 (rogers smcd3gn router).

Ssh localhost -p 2000.
SSH connects locally.

Ssh 192.168.0.10 -p 2000.
SSH connects internal network.

Ssh my.ip.address -p 2000.
SSH connection to port 2000 timed out.

Checked firewall, have inbound/outbound allowing TCP 2000.
http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/ says port 2000 is open. Even set my computer as DMZ in router page. What did I miss that caused this connection to time out?